# stack with simple jquery 2 lvl accordion

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion

I have a simple accorion menu

```
$('.br_filticon li').click(function() {
  var obj = $(this);
  var itemIndex = obj.index();

  obj
  .addClass('current').siblings("li").removeClass('current')
  .parents('ul.br_filticon').find('div.br_filtdescr').slideUp(100)
  .eq(itemIndex).slideDown(100);

  return false;
});
```

Menu works fine if all sections have subsections, but if at least one section has not subsection - problem.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8kkc2bn0/)

Please help fix it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're associating the `li` elements and the `.br_filtdescr` elements by index. Any `li` does not have the sub element the index is then offset.

To fix this, use DOM traversal to find only the `.br_filtdescr` element within the clicked `li` and hide all others, like this:

```
$('.br_filticon li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div.br_filtdescr').slideUp(100)
    $(this).addClass('current').siblings("li").removeClass('current').end()
        .find('div.br_filtdescr').slideDown(100);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8kkc2bn0/1/)